# Netbeans default customized blank web application template

Tags: java, netbeans

Is it possible in netbeans(any version > 6.8) to open one default customized blank template of web application at the time of creation new web application in netbeans.

I have one web application(something added more to scratched project) and i want this web application to get open whenever the user wants to create new web application so that he dont have to add this common steps also at the next time.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own Maven archetype and create netbeans project from that archetype. This way it won't be netbeans-specific and could be reused by non-netbeans users.

See [Archetypes introduction](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) and [Guide for creating archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html)